# Error when importing Minitab (.MTP) into R

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm creating a GUI using Tcltk package and it has a menu to import data files into R from different statistical software such as SAS, Minitab and SPSS but I'm getting an error. For example, if I try to import a .MTP file using the "foreign" package, I get the following error:

```
Error in read.mtp(file = "cars2.mtp") : file read error
```

The code I'm using is below:

```
library(foreign)
test <-  read.mtp(file="C:/R Projects/Examples/cars2.mtp")
```

Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: Re: the specific problem. You should add information about the versions of the software being used. The help page says "This function was written around 1990 for the format current then. Later versions of Minitab appear to have added to the format." You should explore whether there is an Minitab option for writing in an earlier format.  If the problem is more general, then file permissions need attention. I generally find that CSV format is more portable.

Comment: Hi Donal, Thanks for the answer. I agree with you. Is definitely better to work with .csv files, but when you are building a GUI and the client asks to be able to import files from different sources, you have to say yes! LOL. So I saw that this function was written in 1990, but I couldn't find any more recent functions. Do you know if there is any? Thank you very much again for your time!